# Laravel-método update crea un nuevo objeto en vez de editarlo

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Al intentar actualizar una entidad, se crea una nueva. Sospecho que puede ser problema del id de Speciality, que no le está llegando bien a update, pero no lo tengo muy claro. ¿Puede ser por ese motivo o quizás es por otra razón?

**Speciality:**

```
class Speciality extends Model
   {
//
   protected $fillable = ['name','description'];

   public function doctor(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Doctor');
}

public function getName(){
  return $this->name;
}
public function getDescription(){
  return $this->description;
}
}
```

**Método edit-SpecialityController**

```
public function edit( Speciality $speciality)
{
  //dd($speciality);
  return view('specialities/edit')->with('speciality', $speciality);

}
```

**Método update-SpecialityController**

```
public function update(Request $request, Speciality $speciality)
{
//
  $this->validate($request,[
  'name' => 'required|max:300',
  'description' => 'required|max:500'
]);

$speciality->fill($request->all());
$speciality->save();

return Redirect::to('specialities');



   }
```

**EditBlade**

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@include('layouts.menu')
@section('content')
<form action="updateSpeciality" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
<input name="id" type="hidden" value="{{ $id }}"/>

<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <label for="exampleInputName1">Editar nombre</label>
    <input name=name class="form-control" id="exampleInputName1">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-10">
    <label for="exampleInputDescription1">Editar descripción</label>
    <input name="description" class="form-control" id="exampleInputDescription1">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
   </form>
   @endsection
```

**Y las rutas**

```
Route::get('specialities', 'SpecialityController@index');
Route::get('createSpeciality', 'SpecialityController@create');
Route::post('storeSpeciality', 'SpecialityController@store');
Route::get('editSpeciality', 'SpecialityController@edit');
Route::put('updateSpeciality', 'SpecialityController@update');
```

Comment: El `$id` debería formar parte de la ruta como parametro, al mandarlo en el cuerpo no se está recibiendo en el método `update` como segundo parámetro,  por lo que se instancia un objeto nuevo en lugar de recuperar el existente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `$id` debería formar parte de la ruta como parámetro, al mandarlo en el cuerpo no se está recibiendo en el método `@update` como segundo parámetro,  por lo que se instancia un objeto nuevo en lugar de recuperar el existente.

La ruta debería ser algo así para permitir el paso de variables

```
Route::put('updateSpeciality/{speciality}', 'SpecialityController@update');
```

En la vista debería estar el id en la ruta del form en lugar de ser un input, algo como:

```
<form action="updateSpeciality/{{ $id }}" method="POST">
```

Lo mismo con el método `@edit`.

---

Si no quieres hacer nada de esto, debes obtener el id del cuerpo y buscarlo, ejemplo:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
  // Buscamos en la bd el registro
  $speciality = Speciality::findOrFail($request->id);

  // Resto de código 
  $this->validate($request,[
    'name' => 'required|max:300',
    'description' => 'required|max:500'
  ]);

  $speciality->fill($request->all());
  $speciality->save();

  return Redirect::to('specialities');
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, soluciona el problema.

Answer (score 1):

Aunque la respuesta aceptada funciona, existe una mejor forma de hacerlo en Laravel, se llama [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding), de hecho es la práctica recomendada en Laravel.

Al pasar el id en la URL y al especificar que se trata de un identificador de un modelo de speciality y no una simple variable, reduces la cantidad de código que necesitas escribir:

```
Route::put('updateSpeciality/{speciality}', 'SpecialityController@update');
```

Controlador

```
public function update(Speciality $speciality, Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'name' => 'required|max:300',
        'description' => 'required|max:500'
    ]);

    $speciality->fill($request->all());
    $speciality->save();

    return Redirect::to('specialities');
}
```

En otras palabras, el código del método edit y update de tu controlador es (casi) correcto, simplemente debes modificar ligeramente la definición de la ruta.

Comment: Es casi casi lo mismo que yo quise indicar aun que no me fije en que que la variable en este caso deberia ser `speciality` en la ruta para que coincida con el metodo, cosa de costumbres. Igualmente tu desarrollaste un poco mas esa parte.